# EF Core creating matrix grid

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, entity-framework-core, crosstab

My goal is to create a matrix like shown on [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29c3D.png) from database values:

[image: picture]

The object [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSx2p.png) is shown below. I'm using LINQ and Entity Framework Core.

[image]

So I want to get all Users and all Customers that are in database and if there is an entry in UserOrder table for user and order, display the user order value as value in matrix.

I'm then trying to use these values in a [kendo grid](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index).

Hope you understand what I was trying to explain, please ask if there are any unclear details. (I am unfortunately unable to embed images so they have to be included via a link).

Thank you

Comment: EF Core is an ORM, not a grid control. Its job is to Map Relational data to Objects. A matrix isn't an object. What you posted isn't a matrix either, it looks like pivoted data. How you display the data is up to your GUI and your code. What is that picture supposed to show anyway? What are those values? Counts? Totals? Post the *code* information *in the question itself*

Comment: I am trying to retrieve data using EF core in a way to pass them into the framework's grid component. 
What I don't know is how to retrieve them so that there would be a row for each user with colums - user.fullname, user.value, followed by all customer.names

Comment: `I'm then trying to use these values in a kendo grid.` in that case you should ask a Kendo question. What you show looks like *pivoted* data although it's completely unclear what the measure is. Kendo has a pivot table.

Comment: `I am trying to retrieve data using EF core` how you retrieve the data doesn't matter. Again (and again) EF Core is an ORM, not a data access library. If you don't want the objects, don't use an ORM. How you display the objects isn't the job of EF Core either. You haven't explained *what* you want to show though - what are those values? What are they supposed to show? The diagram *doesn't contain any such fields*

Comment: Post the classes and code instead of pictures of the classes, and examples of the input and output *data*, not `User.FullName3`. Is that the actual string you want to display? Or is it the full name of the 3rd user? How many `Customer`s are supposed to be there? A SQL query can't have an arbitrary number of columns. In a web grid though you can add columns in a `foreach` loop. Even then of course, you need to know the maximum number of columns

Comment: In your View code for example, you can add eg 10 columns and then in each row emit as many `td`s as there are order customers

Comment: I was trying to redact company's information to not expose real values and attributes and thought the abstract names would be enough to explain, hence I can't even post any code, unfortunately, even though that would make this much easier to explain. 
I am now looking at the pivot grid you mentioned in your earlier reply as it could possibly do what I am trying to achieve with some configuration.

Comment: Use some dummy values then, and *explain what you want*. As for `I can't even post any code` that's not exactly true. It's impossible to copyright or claim trade secrets on common knowledge and techniques, including code, and writing a LINQ query is *very* common. So are most business problems. If you want to show some aggregate on users vs customers in a matrix report, you can't just bind the results to a grid. Both the rows and columns are determined by data. You'd need a `foreach` loop to generate both the rows and columns.

Comment: The easiest way to produce data for a matrix *report*, is to just execute a `GROUP BY`, load all the data and then generate rows and columns for distinct row and column headers. Some UI elements, like Kendo's Pivot or the open source pivottable.js can handle this kind of information directly. With plain tables you'll have to write the foreach loop.